# Installing Passenger on ubuntu for ruby 1.9 and rails 3, problem with rvm

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, rvm

I am installing passenger on a Ubuntu server 10.04.2. following [this tutorial](http://thekindofme.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/rails-3-on-ubuntu-10-10-with-rvm-passenger-and-nginx/).

When I arrive to the step to install nginx `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module` I have the following error:

> Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old. Please update them first by running 'rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'.

And when I try the command it says:

> ERROR: rvm update has been removed.
>   See 'rvm get' and rvm 'rubygems' CLI
>   API insteadroot@myservername:/srv#

Does anyone know how I could install nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you are missing several libraries or dependencies for Ubuntu to successfully install nginx and passenger webservers

Here is a good link for [setting up passenger with nginx](http://programmingzen.com/2009/11/20/setup-ruby-enterprise-edition-nginx-and-passenger-aka-mod_rails-on-ubuntu/) or better still follow [this list of commands for passenger and nginx](http://www.modrails.com/install.html). There is some great video tutorials on the site to show you how to do this.

Don't use sudo to install the gem when using RVM. This messes with your ruby version.

```
$rvm use 1.9.2
$gem install passenger
$passenger-install.....nginx
```

then

```
$rvm use 1.9.2 --default --passenger
```

I'm not sure if that is correct. I installed as a standalone passenger and nginx. I use RVM also. I'm pretty sure you don't have the necessary dependencies however.

Comment: Thx, following the tutorials you gave me, i installed libcurl4-openssl-dev and it now it works.